# jQuery If "P" tag contains "Img" tag add "Text Align Center to "P" tag

Tags: jquery, image, wordpress, center

I just need a bit of help adding a text align of center to `p` tags if they contain an image. I need this to be able to center attached images within wordpress. Thank you for any and all help you may be able to offer!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`has`](http://api.jquery.com/has/) to narrow down the set of all `p` elements to those which contain `img` elements, and then use [`css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) to change the property:

```
$("p").has("img").css({textAlign: "center"});
```

Alternatively, you could use the [`:has`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector:

```
$("p:has(img)").css({textAlign: "center"});
```

However, the `.has` method is faster than the selector.

Comment: This was perfect and absolutly got the job done! Thank you so much for your help. jQuery is the next focus of my learning path.

Comment: You're absolutely right about the `.has()` being faster: http://jsperf.com/selectorcomparisons, but full marks to SLaks for being fastest..!

Comment: For me in Chrome 16 `.has` is fastest (followed closely by `.closest`).

Answer (score 2):

With jQuery:

```
$('p:has("img")').css('text-align','center');
```

Just because I ran this through [JS Perf](http://jsperf.com/selectorcomparisons/), I thought I'd post a plain JS version (that, in Chromium 14/Ubuntu 11.04, is the fastest approach to solving the problem):

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i=0,len=imgs.length; i<len; i++){
    if (imgs[i].parentNode.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'p'){
        imgs[i].parentNode.style.textAlign = 'center';
    }
}
```

[Along with a JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YsQ2U/).

References:

- [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/).
- [`:has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/).

Answer (score 1):

```
$('img').closest('p').css('text-align', 'center');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use has: http://api.jquery.com/has/

```
$('p').has('img').css('textAlign', 'center');
```